# Return name of object property by value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript object that maps ids:

```
codes = { 
    "admin" : 3,
    "manager" : 2,
    "basic" : 1
}
```

Given a value...

> accountType = 2;

...what is the most elegant way to find the corresponding key ("manager") ?

Comment: What should happen with an object like `{admin:2, manager:2}`?

Comment: For mapping db values to something more readable.  (I'm not interested in using a join table for this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (var i in codes){
    if (codes[i] == accountType)
        alert(i);
}
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PsXYR/)

jQuery version, though there is really no benefit from using it here:

```
$.each(codes, function(key, value){
        if (value == accountType)
            alert(key);
});
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PsXYR/1/)

Comment: Thanks - I was wondering if there might be a way to do this without manually iterating through the properties

Comment: @user1031947, I'm afraid not. Sorry.

Comment: @user1031947, but if the object key value pairs were like: `codes = { 
    "3" : "admin",
    "2" : "manager",
    "1" : "basic"
}
` you could have used this: `codes["2"]`

Answer (score 1):

If you do this a lot, it would be efficient to keep an object to use for the reverse lookup:

```
codeNames = { 
  "3": "admin",
  "2": "manager",
  "1": "basic"
}
```

Now you can just access the properties by name:

```
var name = codeNames[accountType];
```

You can create the lookup object from the `codes` object:

```
var codeNames = {};
for (var i in codes){
  codeNames[codes[i]] = i;
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: +1, though I think it's awful to have two objects to two different lookups. It can cause more pain than gain.